# MSTSC using two of three monitors

Tags: remote-desktop

I have three monitors on my Windows 7 machine, the laptop display and two external.  At the moment I can either have one screen or all screens in multimontor setup (not span) when RDP'd to a server.  Is there any way I can restrict it to only using two out of three so I have a local monitor and the two RDP screens?

I can only find a "one or all" option on mstsc.  Or is there another client that has better support for this type of operation?